# List out of range in simulation

Tags: python

I have been working on an assignment lately and have been stuck at a List Index out of range error. The goal is to simulate and manipulate viruses. Like ["CDTD", "FDFD"]. The elements in the lists can be reproduced, eliminated, changed and added. This depends on a few probabilities like mortalityProb is a float which is the probability that an element will be eliminated, mutationProb is a float which is probability that an element will change/mutate, , maxProductionProb which limits the reproduction size, the maxPopulation is an integer for the maximum amount of elements.

I have added a check that the maxPopulation shouldn't exceed length of the viruses, yet it does not work out.

**Primary function (simulate)**

```
import random
import string

def simulate(viruses, mortalityProb, mutationProb, maxReproductionProb, maxPopulation, timesteps = 500):
    population_sizes = []
    population_sizes.append(len(viruses))

    for t in range(timesteps):
        kill(viruses, mortalityProb)
        reproductionProb = reproductionProbability(viruses, maxReproductionProb, maxPopulation)

        if t >= 100:
            if isResistent(viruses[t]) == True:
                viruses = reproduce(viruses, mutationProb, reproductionProb)
                population_sizes.append(len(viruses[t]))
        else:
            viruses = reproduce(viruses, mutationProb, reproductionProb)
            population_sizes.append(len(viruses))

    return population_sizes
```

**Assertions**
It passes all other checks, but it does not work with the following asserts:

```
viruses = [generateVirus(4) for _ in range(100)]
assert 501 == len(simulate(viruses, 1, 0, 0, 0))

sims = []
n = 100
for i in range(n):
    viruses = [generateVirus(4) for _ in range(100)]
    sims.append(simulate(viruses, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 100, timesteps = 1000)[-1])
average = sum(sims) / n

assert 25 < average < 30
```

**Errors**
Running this code results in a List index out of Range error for:

> if t >= 100 and isResistent(viruses[t]) == True and len(viruses) <= maxPopulation:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-ed2d36f37334> in <module>
      1 # test 1
      2 viruses = [generateVirus(4) for _ in range(100)]
----> 3 assert 501 == len(simulate(viruses, 1, 0, 0, 0))
      4 
      5 # test 2

<ipython-input-22-c07b7cec9184> in simulate(viruses, mortalityProb, mutationProb, maxReproductionProb, maxPopulation, timesteps)
      7         reproductionProb = reproductionProbability(viruses, maxReproductionProb, maxPopulation)
      8 
----> 9         if t >= 100 and isResistent(viruses[t]) == True and len(viruses) <= maxPopulation:
     10             print(viruses)
     11             viruses = reproduce(viruses, mutationProb, reproductionProb)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thank you for helping out! I hope this question is conform the guidelines of StackOverflow. If you have any comments, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When generating the viruses it's zero-indexing. So youre generating `viruses[0]` to `viruses[99]`. `viruses[100]` do not exist.

I dont really get, why you want the virus based on the timestep t? Maybe you want to iterate through your viruses, not the timesteps?

```
for v in range(len(viruses)-1):
    if isResistent(viruses[v]) == True:
            viruses = reproduce(viruses, mutationProb, reproductionProb)
            population_sizes.append(len(viruses[v]))
    else:
        viruses = reproduce(viruses, mutationProb, reproductionProb)
        population_sizes.append(len(viruses))
```

> I have added a check that the maxPopulation shouldn't exceed length of the viruses, yet it does not work out.

this check would probably be:

```
if len(population_sizes) > len(viruses):
    break
```

Comment: This has to do with the output. **return population_size** should return an integer of every time step as a list.

Comment: Ok i see! Well your problem is just you are creating 100 viruses is your test and trying to acces to 101st virus with your function. In your test you're even killing all the virus with mortality prob 1. Please check if the first part of my answer makes any sense to you